# Bind normal js variable as an angular object key

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array of objects, `objects`, and a a few JS variables holding static strings, such as `static1`, `static2` ...  How can I accomplish the following:

```
<tr ng-repeat="obj in objects">
    <td>{{obj[static1]}}</td> 
    <td>{{obj[static2]}}</td> 
    ...
</tr>
```

**EDIT**: `static1` and `static2` are JS variables, ie. `var static1 = "something"`

Comment: static1 will be json key right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller where you define `$scope.objects`, also define:

```
$scope.static1 = 'nameOfObjectProperty1';
$scope.static2 = 'nameOfObjectProperty2';
```

and it should evaluate correctly.

Comment: static1 and static2 are normal variables, not angularjs scope variables

Comment: everything you put in expressions like `obj[static1]` has to be on the angular scope. `obj` is (`ng-repeat` puts it). It's how angular works.

Comment: apparently its the only way to go... I thought there might be a trick or so

Comment: will change to any object dynamically reflect?
say, `obj[static1]` is changed on certain `onclick` function

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this

**[Working Code](http://jsfiddle.net/uRPSL/91/)**

**html**

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="ArrayController">
    <table border="1">
     <th ng-repeat="header in headers"> <b>{{ headers[$index]}}</b></th>
     <tr ng-repeat="arr in records">
        <td ng-repeat="val in arr" ng-bind-html-unsafe="arr[headers[$index]]">
        </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**script**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('ArrayController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.headers = ['static1', 'static2'];
    $scope.records = [{
        static1: 'a1',
        static2: 'd1'
    }, {
        static1: 'c2',
        static2: 'A2'
    }, {
        static1: 'b3',
        col2: 'c3'
    }, {
        static1: 'd4',
        static2: 'a1'
    }, {
        static1: '11',
        static2: '22'
    }, {
        static1: 'E1',
        static2: 'E2'
    }];
});
```